# Ambiguity in Hashmap?

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap, unordered-map

I have used unordered map or hash map many times  but this is the firsttime  I am encountering problem like this :
if I run this code :

```
string s  = "dvd";
for(int i = 0;i < s.size();i++){
        if(!map[s[i]]){
            cout<<s[i];
            map[s[i]] = i;
        }
    }
```

the output is

```
d v d
```

My question since already d is in map , so why the code printing it again.
And another interesting thing is that when i run this code

```
    string s = "dvd";

    unordered_map<char,int>map;
    for(auto i :s){
        if(!map[i]){
            cout<<i<<" ";
            map[i] = i;
        }    
    }
```

it gives the expected output which is

```
d v
```

What is the thing I am missing here??

Comment: `i = 0` is false.

Comment: so value can't be 0 ? and now i tried using map.find(s[i]) == map.end() and it works fine , any idea why??

Comment: Because thats the correct way to check whether a map contains a given key.

Comment: Oh i get it thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite easy to explain what happens if you understand that the integer `0` is converted to the boolean value `false` (and anything non-zero is `true`), and how the [ranged `for` loop work](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

---

If we begin with the first loop:

```
for(int i = 0;i < s.size();i++){
    if(!map[s[i]]){
        cout<<s[i];
        map[s[i]] = i;
    }
}
```

Here the variable `i` represents the *index* of the characters in the string. The indexes will be (in order) `0`, `1` and `2`.

With the first iteration, the `'d'` doesn't exist, so `map[s[i]]` will create an element with a zero value, and return the zero value. That makes the condition be `!0` which is true, so you print the character and then assign the index `0` to `map['d']` (which already *is* `0`).

The second iteration is the same, but you assign the value `1` to `map['v']`.

Then you get to the third iteration, where `map['d']` already exist. ***But*** since the value is `0` your condition believe it doesn't exist.

So your condition is flawed. To check if a key doesn't exist use either [`count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/count)

```
if (map.count(s[i]) == 0)
```

Or you can use [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find)

```
if (map.find(s[i]) == map.end())
```

Or when C++20 comes you can use [`contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/contains)

```
if (map.contains(s[i]))
```

---

Then the second loop:

```
for(auto i :s){
    if(!map[i]){
        cout<<i<<" ";
        map[i] = i;
    }    
}
```

Here `i` isn't an index it's a *character*. So the values you assign to the map elements with `map[i] = i` will not be `0`, `1` or `2`, it will be the encoded character values which for ASCII will be `100` for the character `'d'` and `118` for `'v'`.

So in the first iteration `map[i]` will be zero (just like before) but then you assign `100` to that element.

In the second iteration it's the same but you assign the value `118`.

Now we come back to the letter `'d'` with the value `100`. When you check `map['d']` the second time, the value isn't zero, and you have `!100` which is `false`.